# Can't run javafx application in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

For an assignment I need to edit a Javafx application provided by the teacher.  The executable jar runs fine, but when I try to run the application in Eclipse I get many errors. I am having similar errors with another javafx application that runs in eclipse but the exported jar won't run.

Here is the main method:

```
package mypackage;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RectangeMath extends Application {
       @Override
       public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
          Parent root =
             FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("RectangleMath.fxml"));

          Scene scene = new Scene(root); // attach scene graph to scene
          stage.setTitle("Rectangule Math"); // displayed in window's title bar
          stage.setScene(scene); // attach scene to stage
          stage.show(); // display the stage
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          // create a TipCalculator object and call its start method
          launch(args);
       }
    }
```

Here are the errors I get when trying to run.

```
Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:  /C:/Users/sethc/OneDrive/Documents/SLCCsu2018/MySourceCode/IntroToGUIs/IntroToGUIsAttempt4/bin/mypackage/RectangleMath.fxml:9
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at mypackage.RectangeMath.start(RectangeMath.java:13)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RectangleMathController
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
    ... 22 more
 Exception running application mypackage.RectangeMath
```

Comment: You're probably not using the fully qualified class name of the controller class in the `fx:controller` attribute of the fxml, but this is impossible to tell without seeing the fxml.

Comment: Which project type are you using?

Comment: @fabian I am using the same files that were in my professor's existing executable jar which works fine, so I'm not sure if the code is the problem unless there is an error with the file paths in my new project.  I suspected some part of eclipse that i am not using correctly.  Please let me know if you disagree

Comment: @Greg I have tried both java project and javafx project types with the same results

Comment: You need to make absolutely sure there is a class with the name `RectangleMathController` in the default package (use `fx:controller="packagename.RectangleMathController"` if it's not part of the default package). Also make sure you include the `.class` file for the controller class in the classpath at runtime.

Comment: @fabian thanks for clarifying that for me; I did need to update the package name.  I kept running into this problem since he keeps giving us the files to work with but I have to build new projects for them so details like this are hard to make consistent.  Feel free to paste into the answer.  Thanks again!